OneDrive MS Graph API only allows for query for jpg images only now?
It seems that OneDrive MS Graph API only allows for query for jpg images only now?
Previously, this MS Graph Explorer endpoint would be able to load obj files but has changed to only search from jpg images only?
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.obj')?select=name,id,@content.downloadUrl

In my case, querying with .obj also worked like this https://i.imgur.com/D7xXZxK.png. Check whether your root drive has files with .obj or not.

does it have to be in the root drive? can it query subdirectories?

Yes, it can query subdirectories of root drive too

Initially, run below Graph API call and confirm what path your root drive is referring to like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root

Response:

Now, check whether your root drive or it's sub directories have files with .obj format or not as below:

FolderA:

SubFolderA:

When I ran below call in Graph Explorer to load .obj files, I got response successfully like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.obj')?select=name

Response:


do you know what happened to downloadURL? https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.obj')?select=name,id,@content.downloadUrl
in this query the downloadURL no longer shows

@ina The @content.downloadUrl can be retrieved only when you specifically access a single driveItem, not when listing multiple items via a search query.

After getting id's of drive items from search query, run this call to get download URL: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/itemID?select=id,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl like this https://i.imgur.com/qGv9UdD.png

Hi @ina Any update?

it used to be you could...

so this seems to intermittently fail. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.obj')?select=name,id

also should this also work in getting downloadURL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/"+ itemid+ "/content

Yes. for getting downloadURL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/itemID/content also works. Did your issue resolved?

nope that keeps doing the 401 error even when authenticating with token?

fetching @downloadURL the single driveItem json works

okay so the issue seems to be that sometimes null values is returned given the same search query

if u ran this using curl, which headers are you sending ?

What do you mean by using curl? Are you generating bearer token and calling API with it? Please post a new question with more details and share link here

does this work for ou - curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='\''.obj'\'')?select=name%2Cid' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --header 'Authorization: ••••••'

yes the bearer token is generated but for some reason the search returns null from my app (which calls using curl) unless you use the graph explorer interface, and then the curl statement works... each time the token is being extracted through oauth.

is there some sort of other endpoint to have the file list build or cache to prevent null listings?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79231270/ms-graph-explorer-request-curl-equivalent-call-token-already-avail
