MS Graph Explorer Request Curl Equivalent Call (Token Already Avail)
It seems graph api calls from curl do not match what the graph explorer interface does. For example, this would intermittently return a null values list but something the explorer does causes it to return a non-null values list, with the same graph search url.
curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='\''.obj'\'')?select=name%2Cid' \ 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ 
--header 'Authorization: ••••••'

What is the actual equiv curl request that graph explorer is calling?
